# Lost information after set association between user an employee in odoo 12

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

I want to create a user when creating an employee so far is working fine

```
@api.model
    @api.returns('self', lambda value: value.id)
    def create(self, vals):
        rec = super(HrEmployee, self).create(vals)
        model = {
            'name': rec.name,
            'login': rec.work_email,
            'sel_groups_1_9_10':9, # user type, portal user
            'company_id':1,
            'write_uid': 1,
            'share': False,
            'image':rec.image_medium
        }

        domain = [('login','=',rec.work_email)]
        users = self.env['res.users'].search(domain)

        if not users:
            try:
                user = self.env['res.users'].create(model)
                rec.user_id = user.id

            except Exception as e:
                logging.info(e)
                pass

        return rec
```

The issue is that after I set **rec.user_id = user.id** the employee **work_email**, converts to None, any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because the new user `email` is empty.

There is an [on change method](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/hr/models/hr.py#L228) that updates the employee's `work_email` with the related user [email](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/hr/models/hr.py#L241).